# Adb shell while read file

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

I have been trying since couple of hours and either I am having a bad day or just not that creative today.

I am trying to send commands trough ADB using variables from a text file but it doesn't seem to work.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

file.txt

**Alex

26

USA**

script.sh

**while read line

do

adb shell input text $line

do < file.txt**

I want to have output as 
adb shell input text Alex
adb shell input text 26
adb shell input text USA

But I keep getting adb shell input text Alex
and somehow output as 
echo "26"
echo "USA"

Any help is appreciated
Thanks a lot

Comment: it's `done < file.txt` not `do < file.txt`

Comment: Sorry about that.
It is done but still the same problem occurs.